# Editing inner HTML of an element not working

Tags: c#, .net, html, webbrowser-control

My goal is to add some specific HTML inside a table body.

Code notes:

- tbody points to the body
- "Hello \n" is very simple word for example I want to add
- I've the HTML stored in another variable

Now each time I get exception & it doesn't accept my Edit

```
var tbody = table.GetElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
//tbody.InnerHtml = " </br> ";
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    try
    {
        tbody.InnerHtml = tbody.InnerHtml + "Hello \n";
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I also tried another method but the result was:

[image]

**Update 2:**

This is a desktop application , I  want to change in the innerHtml value for a table  that I obtained from WebBrowser Control

**Update 3:**

*Exception*

System.NotSupportedException was caught
Message=Property is not supported on this type of HtmlElement.
Source=System.Windows.Forms
StackTrace:
at System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement.set_InnerHtml(String value)
at WebScraper.Form1.webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted(Object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) in E:\Companies-work\FreeLancer\WebScraper\WebScraper\WebScraper\Form1.cs:line 248
InnerException:

**Update 4:**

*Checking if tbody is null or not*
[image]

Comment: @HatSoft HTML table , I'm accessing it via webbrowser control

Answer (score 0):

if tbody is an HtmlElement as shown in below line

```
var tbody = table.GetElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
```

Then you can directly use the InnerHtml property of it, instead of the lines shown in your printscreen

like this

```
tbody.InnerHtml += "Hello \n";
```

Comment: @xsari3x please can you get the InnerException and post if for me

Comment: System.NotSupportedException was caught
  Message=Property is not supported on this type of HtmlElement.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement.set_InnerHtml(String value)
       at WebScrapper.Form1.webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted(Object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) in E:\Companies-work\FreeLancer\WebScrapper\WebScrapper\WebScrapper\Form1.cs:line 248
  InnerException:

Comment: @xsari3x looks like tbody is null or not an HtmlElement type, please check and let me know

Comment: check the Update4 , an image was uploaded

Comment: @xsari3x instead of InnerHtml please try the concatenation with InnerText

Comment: I tried innerText , it makes me lose the HTML format , only text appears

Comment: @xsari3x innerText will insert text in to htlmlElement so why not try inserting something like this e.g. "<h1>Hello</h1>" that wya you you will get you r html format back with the new text

Comment: I tried to insert HTML formatted text inside it using innerText & still the same !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14451/discussion-between-hatsoft-and-xsari3x)